# Jetty Error: I' starting my web aap and all of sudden Getting this Error

Tags: ant, jetty

I'm using Ant build tool. Do you any any idea How to resolve this issue
looks like it is not working because of this website: https://eclipse.dev/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd
Error message:

> 2024-02-14 13:56:53.815:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.43.v20210629;
> built: 2021-08-10T13:32:34.286Z; git: unknown; jvm 17+35-2724
> 2024-02-14 13:56:56.912:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context
> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@276438c9{/deploymentcenter,file:///D:/workdir/devunits/2312_Sept_Basleline/src/deploymentcenter/webapp/com.dc.webapp/src/main/WebContent/,STOPPED}{D:\workdir\devunits\2312_Sept_Basleline\src\deploymentcenter\webapp\com.dc.webapp\src\main\WebContent}
> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: https://eclipse.dev/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1997)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:677)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1399)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1365)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:257)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1152)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1040)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:943)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:326)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:244)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Descriptor.parse(Descriptor.java:53)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebDescriptor.parse(WebDescriptor.java:213)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.setDefaults(MetaData.java:167)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.preConfigure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:48)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:488)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:523)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
> at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9Adapter.start(Jetty9Adapter.java:68)
> at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
> at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
> 2024-02-14 13:56:56.957:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6895a785{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9092
>
> ```
> I went to this website and looks like it is not running: https://eclipse.dev/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd
> ```

Comment: All versions of Jetty 11 and older (including your Jetty 9) are now at End of Community Support - see https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/7958 and https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/10485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty [9.4.43.v20210629 is at End of Community Support](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/7958) and [is a version that is vulnerable](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/security_reports.php).

You have a configuration that is using a DTD at the XML System ID of `https://eclipse.dev/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd` which means two things.

1. You have a configuration for Jetty 10 (or newer)
2. You have a configuration using the new `eclipse.dev` hostname (this is a new hostname from 2023)

To address this, you must upgrade your version of Jetty.

The current supported version of Jetty is Jetty 12, and its `ee8` environment can be used to run webapps that still use the `javax.servlet` namespace.